# How to download up to 2GB telegram files with NodeJS

Tags: telegram

I simply can't find an answer, but given a link to a Telegram video, how do I, using NodeJS, download that video? It seems I can use a bot to download up to 20MB, and then there are services that allow you to download entire channels up to 2GB at a file, but I just want a single file downloaded. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local bot API server for that. see the official bot API docs for details: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server